# Showing bookmarks in new tab in firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I would like to enable Firefox to show only my bookmarks as tiles 
I open a new tab. I *don't* want it to show tiled snapshots of the past sites I have visited which is the current default behaviour.

I find this would be much more convenient than having a bookmarks toolbar, 
which takes up some of my screen space.

Answer (score 5):

Migrated from Chrome to Firefox and I was scared not to have my bookmarks shown on a new tab.
Good lord, the same extension is available on Firefox too:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/humble-new-tab/

[image]

Comment: This is great! I added a bookmark folder which I use as one column, doing exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Currently using Firefox 61.0.1, the old methods no longer exist/work. Now you can either [add them manually](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_customize-your-top-sites) or use Highlights.

If you choose to use **Top Sites**, you can [add](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_add-a-top-site) your own sites, [pin](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_pin-a-top-site) them, and [dismiss](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_remove-a-top-site) the ones you don't want to see.

You can also set the number of rows you want (1 or 2 rows) in Firefox's options.

For **Highlights**, you can just have Bookmarks checked but it will only update once you add new bookmarks. It will not pull any old bookmarks so you'll have to add them again.

[image: Highlights]

### Outdated

Yes, you can do this.

You can either [change the new tab page itself](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_add-a-tile-from-your-bookmarks)

> You can set the value of the pref **browser.newtab.url** using **about:config** to
> *chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksPanel.xul*

or

[Drag the bookmarks you want to the tiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page#w_add-a-tile-from-your-bookmarks).

Comment: the pref `browser.newtab.url` is not present in firefox v46

Comment: The URL ` chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksPanel.xul` gives a "File not found" error as of Firefox 61.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I dug thru the `omni.ja` (actually a `.jar` archive) file mentioned in the old URL's error, and figured out a URL that works for getting the bookmarks sidebar, which can still be set as the home page in `about:preferences#home` . The URL is `chrome://browser/content/places/bookmarksSidebar.xul` . I haven't figured out how to get something more like the bookmarks manager, but this update works.

Comment: Browsing a bit more, I found `chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul` for "Library" (bookmarks manager). There are lots of other cool URLs to find with `.xul` files, but they're off-topic.
(It's too late to edit my previous comment.)

Comment: Nice! I don't have the time to look into it but if it would answer OP's question, I think it would do nicely as an answer