# How to hide firefox bookmarks by default when in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks, tabs

In google chrome, I am able to hide the toolbar when on any tab except the new tab by the ctrl-shift-b command. How may I have the same functionality in firefox? I want my bookmarks to show in the firefox new tab, and I want it to hide automatically when in any other tab, until I do ctrl-shift-b.

Comment: I've posted my answer to this question in this thread [Show bookmarks on new tab](https://superuser.com/questions/1283874/how-to-show-bookmarks-toolbar-only-on-new-tabs-in-firefox/1469244#1469244)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in Firefox, unfortunately.

Comment: That is a bit of a bummer. Is there some extension or script allowing one to get similar functionality?

Comment: As far as I know, no.