# How to show bookmarks toolbar only on new tabs in Firefox SINCE v72

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

You may look at the title and go ["this question is answered here".](https://superuser.com/questions/1283874/how-to-show-bookmarks-toolbar-only-on-new-tabs-in-firefox?newreg=460d532c540849dc90ece4c839c56294)

Well, ever since v72, firefox did something ([I think removed the title attribute for main window, as said here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1276972) ). So that CSS, nor any other works anymore ever since the update.

So, with that said, **How can I make Firefox show the bookmarks toolbar only on new tabs, like Chrome does by default?**? I like using it, but don't need it on EVERY SINGLE PAGE I go to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly the same as the previous way of doing it but it's close. This will only show the bookmarks toolbar when the urlbar is in focus. This happens if you hover/click it. It also happens automatically on new tab.

You can choose which behavior you want or don't want by deleting/commenting out the sections at the bottom.

I found this method through this discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/elxyng/ff_72_broke_my_userchrome_css_rule_for_the/fdlbze2/). The author of this code on GitHub is [MrOtherGuy](https://github.com/MrOtherGuy).

Put this in your [`userChrome.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) file.

```
#PersonalToolbar{
  --uc-bm-height: 20px; /* Might need to adjust if the toolbar has other buttons */
  --uc-bm-padding: 3px; /* Vertical padding to be applied to bookmarks */
}

:root[uidensity="compact"] #PersonalToolbar{ --uc-bm-padding: 1px }
:root[uidensity="touch"] #PersonalToolbar{ --uc-bm-padding: 6px }

#PersonalToolbar:not([customizing]){
    margin-bottom: calc(2px - var(--uc-bm-height) - 2 * var(--uc-bm-padding));
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 135ms linear 600ms !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
#PlacesToolbarItems > .bookmark-item{ padding-block: var(--uc-bm-padding) !important; }

/* SELECT BOOKMARKS TOOLBAR BEHAVIOR */
/* Comment out or delete either one of these to disable that behavior */

/* Show when urlbar is focused */
#nav-bar:focus-within + #PersonalToolbar{
  transition-delay: 100ms !important;
  transform: rotateX(0);
}

/* Show when cursor is over the toolbar area */
#navigator-toolbox:hover > #PersonalToolbar{
    transition-delay: 100ms !important;
    transform: rotateX(0);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/autohide_bookmarks_toolbar.css

Comment: Not exactly like what I wanted but it's close enough, if I'm typing something in the url bar it's not like I'm gonna care about the page, I'm about to leave it anyway.

I deleted the "when the cursor is over the toolbar area" part of course.

Thank you so very much!

Comment: If Firefox ever implements the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) CSS selector, I might be able to make the old method work. But who knows what Firefox will get rid of by then :)

Comment: Since the latest update today, this no longer works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a config for this. The steps as described in e.g. [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-firefox-bookmarks-toolbar-only-on-new-tab-page) or [here](https://winaero.com/how-to-show-firefox-bookmarks-toolbar-only-on-new-tab/) did work for me (in Firefox 116):

- go to `about:config` (enter in address bar)
- if necessary: click on the "Accept the Risk and Continue" button
- Search in the config settings for `browser.toolbars.bookmarks.2h2020`
- Set this to `true` (if it is not)
- Then you can right-click on the title bar of Firefox and select "Bookmarks Toolbar" > "Choose Only on New Tab"